# How do you declare a JavaScript Class Method outside of the class?

Tags: javascript, class

I was watching this video about modules, and this guy (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRHQNNcYf6s), who I DO NOT recommend you ever watch, declared two functions outside of the class, which execute a `console.log` that prints out `${this.name}`, a property declared inside the `constructor()`.

First of all, I have never, ever seen that before, it makes zero sense to me, because how exactly does `${this}` refer to the `constructor()`!? .. but anyway, it works for the guy, so I replicated the code 1:1 identical, and unsurprisingly, it's not working for me! It keeps telling me that `{this.name}` is not defined, which is to be expected, but how is it working for him!? Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the code:

```js
class User { 
    constructor(name, age) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}


function printName(user) { 
    console.log(`User's name is ${this.name}`)
}

function printAge(user) { 
    console.log(`User's age is ${this.age}`)
}


const user = new User("Bob", 11);


printName(user)
```

In his original code, he exported the class and the two functions, and imported them, but the code is identical.

Is this code supposed to work? It's not working for me. It tells me `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

How are `printName` and `printAge` linked to the class `User`? Is the parameter `(user)` supposed to be the name of the instantiated object, or the name of the class? or something else? If we assume it's the name of the instantiated object, how does passing the object to the function somehow links it to the class and makes the function a method of the class!?

Please explain this to me..

Comment: inside those methods `this` refers to the window object.

Comment: He was telling this `function printName(user) { 
    console.log('User's name is ${user.name}')
}` and that works

Comment: Hey man your question is not correct  you should watch it again and you'll find your question was nothing but misunderstanding !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a screenshot from that video.

[image: code screenshot]

As you can see, Kyle from Web Dev Simplified uses the `user` variable passed in by reference, not `this`.

Your proper code (with this changed) is:

```js
class User { 
    constructor(name, age) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}


function printName(user) { 
    console.log(`User's name is ${user.name}`)
}

function printAge(user) { 
    console.log(`User's age is ${user.age}`)
}


const user = new User("Bob", 11);


printName(user);
printAge(user);
```

> How are `printName` and `printAge` linked to the class User?

They aren't "linked", when an object gets passed in with a `.name` or `.age` property it prints that (depending on the function) and if it doesn't it throws an error. It doesn't have to be a `User` class instance

> Is the parameter (user) supposed to be the name of the instantiated object, or the name of the class? or something else?

It's just the name that you'll call the variable passed in, it could be `bob` with no negative impact. When you pass in a `User` class instance, `user` is a reference to that class instance in memory.

> If we assume it's the name of the instantiated object, how does passing the object to the function somehow links it to the class and makes the function a method of the class!?

It does not "link it to the class and make the function a method of the class", you would either need to put a function similar to this in the `class User { ... }` or change `User.prototype.*`

##### If you want to actually make this a class method (where you don't have to pass in an instance), you can do this instead (where you alter the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Prototype))

```js
class User { 
    constructor(name, age) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}


User.prototype.printName = function printName() { 
    console.log(`User's name is ${this.name}`)
}

User.prototype.printAge = function printAge() { 
    console.log(`User's age is ${this.age}`)
}


const user = new User("Bob", 11);


user.printName();
user.printAge();
```

Comment: Okay, apparently my rage-bordering short frustration has blinded my eyes, and I saw "user" as "this". I apologize for that. So you're saying that, when I trigger the function and pass to it as a parameter the object of the Class, then the parameter of the function that I declared makes a reference to the `constructor()`? And so, even if I type `function myFunc(tototo)` and then inside I say `${tototo.name}`, because `tototo` refers to the `constructor()`, it's the same as if using `this` inside the class itself? Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of. I don't know why you think `constructor()` has anything to do with this; it doesn't. `constructor()`, as the name implies, is ran once when the instance is created (`const user = new User("Bob", 11)`) and never ran again. `user` is just an `Object` that has the prototype of `User` linked to it, and the values set in the `constructor()` are values on the object itself.

Comment: I know that the newly created object `user` makes a reference to the class `User`, but I didn't know you could pass the object as a parameter, and then have access to the variables defined inside of the class. I think I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. Sorry to bother you again, but do you mind me asking you one more thing? When importing all the exports using the alias `*`, how do I know instantiate a class object? `import * as stuff from ...`, now I can easily say stuff.myFunc() etc. but what if I want to instantiate a class object? How do I do it? `const myObj = new stuff.User()` doesn't work. So, how do I do it?

Comment: @ihatefacebook Not sure what you mean. Make sure you're exporting properly: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dust-fbhcm?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It only works if `User` is not set to default export. If I type `export default class User {}`, and then import them with alias `*`, `stuff.User` gives me an error - `stuff.User is not a constructor`. If I export `User` not as default, then it works. So, can I use `*` to import all, including a default export?

Answer (score 1):

You could do with [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance#getting_started) method . You will access same class variables

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}


User.prototype.printName = () => {
  console.log(`User's name is ${this.name}`)
}

User.prototype.printAge = () => {
  console.log(`User's age is ${this.age}`)
}


const user = new User("Bob", 11);

console.log(user.name)
user.printName()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you say is indeed not possible, but that's not what he is doing here anyway.
He does not use `${this.age}`, but `${user.age}`